# MFC: Visual Studio Resource Editor Class Wizard doesn't have all control IDs under Member Variables

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mfc, resource-editor, classwizard

I've run into this a few times, don't recall what I did to fix it last time (probably started all over).   Here's what I did:

I copied an existing `CMFCPropertySheet` dialog box and pasted as new one then edited the dialog ID to IDD_MINE, deleted all the controls as a starting place.  Next I added the various controls for the this dialog.

After setting up the dialog the way I wanted it, I went to "Add Class" and added a class for the dialog (choosing the base class `CMFCPropertySheet`). When it was done, it was incorrect (VS2017 has never done the property sheet correct for me).  Referencing another property sheet that I have working, I added the missing IDD_MINE to the constructor and the AFX_DESIGN_TIME { enum IDD=IDD_MINE }.

Once the class was setup I was ready to start adding variables.  However I noticed some of the controls that were a checkbox should have been a radio button so I deleted them, created radio buttons (push like) then choose the existing IDC_ names (old checkbox names) from the dropdown list for the control id.  Next I try to add the first radio button as a *value* variable but that fails with the following error:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

So I go to the Class Wizard for the Dialog and look in "Member Variables" tab.   It lists all the controls IDs except the radio buttons (and IDC_STATIC items that are -1) .   I tried renaming the radio buttons by changing the IDC_ names but that didn't change anything (exit program, etc.., still same).

So does someone know how I get visual stdio resource editor / class wizard back in sync with the controls that really exist so I can add them using the wizard?

TIA!!

EDIT:

Even those variables which exist in the "Member Variables" tab can't be used with the wizard.  Same **Object Reference not set to instance of an object message**.

So being desperate, I manually added the function:

```
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
```

Everything works now!!

Which the wizard would take care of all this on its own.

Comment: The class wizard is basically broken since Visual Studio 2010 (maybe,I'm not sure) and Microsoft just don't fix it, but rather making it worse.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that has been my experience too.